# Get multiple select attribute values

Tags: magento-1.9, product, admin, attributes

I have one multiple select attribute with the name 'recommendations' and I want to get the attribute values in the product list.

I create this code to get values. But now I want to replace **i tag** with **Admin value**: `<i class="admin value"></i>`  and `<span><?php echo $_target ?></span>` with **Default Store View** values. How I can get this values separately?

I need to get **Admin value** and **Default Store View** in the same code.

```
<?php  if ($targetValues = $_product->getAttributeText('recommendations')) { ?> 
<div class="recommended-title"><?php echo $this->__('recommendations') ?></div>
<?php 
if (is_string($targetValues)) {
$targetValues = array($targetValues);
}
foreach($targetValues as $_target) :?>
<ul class="list-inline recommended-logo">
<li>
<i class="<?php echo $_target ?>"></i><span><?php echo $_target ?></span></li>
</ul>
<?php endforeach;
 }
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code to get multi-select values and then you can foreach loop for each attribute value.

```
<?php $targetValue = explode(",", $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('recommendations')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)); ?>
<?php  if(count($targetValue) > 0 ): ?> 
    <div class="recommended-title"><?php echo $this->__('recommendations') ?></div>
    <?php foreach($targetValues as $key=>$val): ?>
    <ul class="list-inline recommended-logo">
        <li>
            <i class="<?php echo $key ?>"></i><span><?php echo $val ?></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi thank you, but I think is not the best idea to use explode

Comment: without explode command it will gives all you select values in comma separated. For example, value1, value2, value 3

Comment: can you give me an example? how will work with explode? can you edit your answer with the code that contain explode too?

Comment: Please check my edited code and let me know if you have any query in that

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: ok in foreach must be this without s at the end $targetValue, but I have the same value for both, for i tag and for span tag

Comment: ohh yeah.. spelling mistake.. is it working now?

Comment: is work but I have the same values, for example for first <li> I have Title for Recom1 in both, in i tag and in span tag, for example I need to have 'recom1' value for i tag and for span tag I need to have Title for Recom1

Comment: check my edit again in code

Comment: you test this code? is work for you? because now, at the i tag I have 0,1,2,3,..,. values

Comment: Switch it over. Try either way.. Put $val inside i tag

Comment: I have the same value now, for both, for span and for i and the value is: Title for Recom1

Comment: can you tell me again what you understand? what I need? because I have the feeling that you don't understand what I want. So I want in the i tag to have Admin attribute value, I mean in my example recom1 and for the span tag I need the Default Store View this is mean Title for Recom1

Comment: whatever you entered inside "Admin" is just lable for Admin. Its not any kind of value. https://trellis.co/blog/managing-attributes-attribute-sets-magento-1-9/

Comment: so if is just for Admin, what do your code?

Comment: Count will echo 1 even if no attribute is selected.

Comment: @loeffel is it multi-select attribute?

Comment: @Abhishek Panchal Yes, it is. It is not a huge problem though because I can use > 1 instead of > 0.